# Nested ListView in Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to achieve this output [Refer snapshot :
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyiHz.png)]

I tried Using, since I am new to Qt not sure whether my approach of using repeater is right or wrong.

```
ListView {
id: outer
model: model1
delegate: model2
anchors.fill: parent
}

Component {
    id: model1
    Item {
        Column{
            Repeater {
                model: 3
                Rectangle {
                    id: rect
                    anchors.top: parent.bottom
                    width: 300
                    height: 30
                    color: listColor2[index]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Component {
    id: model2
    Column{
        Repeater {
            model: 4
            Rectangle {
                id: rect
                
                width: 150
                height: 30
                color: listColor[index]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Column/Repeater combination essentially does the same thing a ListView does, so you're being redundant there. Your delegate should just define what an *individual* item looks like. Your model should describe the data that needs to be displayed. Read through the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#example-usage) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.
Obtained output [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpUm6.png)

```
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    
    
    ListView {
        id: outer
        model: 4
        delegate:
            Rectangle {
            id: rect
            color: listColor[index]
            width: 60
            implicitHeight: col.height
            Column{
                id: col
                anchors.left: rect.right
                Repeater {
                    id: lv2

                    model: 4
                    Rectangle {
                        id: rect2
                        color: listColor2[index]
                        width: 200
                        height: 20
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```